# Which tutorial should i follow?

Tags: ros, arduino, catkin, tutorial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi sir,
i'm trying to understand and make robot using arduino. however i'm confused to learn which tutorial should i follow?
i mean should i go for catkin tutorials or for main ros one?
at present, i have installed indigo and ubuntu 14.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206241/which-tutorial-should-i-follow?/) by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) on 2015-03-30**:
What kind of robot and what task are you considering to do ? From [ardigos](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Products) we page it seams they specialize in hardware devices. I would need a bit more details to give you a clean answer.

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-03-31**:
just as same as industrial robot like kuka or abb. it will have its own processor for working, teach pendant and a computer for simulation. however, i want the simulation both in realtime as well as in offline mode. for it i'm trying to understand which software should i follow first. i searched....

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-03-31**:
.....alot and found ros can be a way. now the problem is i'm from mechanical background,so dont have much knowledge of ubuntu but i love programming and interested to do it myself. obviously, i dont have much knowledge of microcontrollers, so i decided to go for arduino.now the basic question is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should start with the beginner ROS tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) so that you understand the general ROS framework. Reading the catkin tutorials will give you a better understanding of the way workspaces and packages are structured.

To understand how to create a description (URDF) of your robot for integration with simulation (Gazebo), you can take a look at the URDF tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials), which then lead into the Gazebo + ROS URDF Tutorials (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf).

If you want to write controllers for your robot that will work for both live-operation and simulation, you should take a look at ros_control (http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control/Tutorials). This last part will definitely require some digging and a good understanding of ROS and Gazebo first. The Husky robot uses ros_control's diff_drive_controller (http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) for mobile base control, so you can take a look at the way it's implemented here:

https://github.com/husky/husky

https://github.com/husky/husky_simulator

https://github.com/husky/husky_robot/blob/indigo-devel/husky_base/src/husky_base.cpp

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I take it this is a side project then ? Well ROS only deals with communication between different software and middleware components. If you need a physical simulation for your robot and want to be able to switch between controlling the real robot and it's simulated counterpart the Ros + Rviz + Gazebo software packages is what you will want.

Gazebo is a physics simulator, which is meant  to represent the real physical world with your robot. A good  [Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) here shows how to control a stick robot with a camera and IR sensor.

For ROS it is much easier there are plenty of good tutorials such as the turtle bot ones: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics.

Rviz is a visualisation display, it is to show you the state of the robot and all sensory information available. You use this both when you are running your simulation in Gazebo and when you are running the real robot.

---

Originally posted by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) with karma: 285 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1